# Why the latest Python 3.8.x release provides no Windows installer?

Tags: python, windows-installer

I need to install Python 3.8 on a Windows computer and hope to use the latest minor version of [3.8.12](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3812/). The official release web page provides tarball files of the source code but no Windows installer. Python 3.8.10 provides Windows installers, but it is not the latest version.

I am wondering:

- Why v3.8.12 does not provide any Windows installer?
- If we want to use v3.8.12, what can we do?

I appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: The linked page itself says why: "Finally, **while we're not providing binary installers anymore**, ...". It's not just that they aren't providing a Windows installer, they aren't providing *any* binary installers.

Comment: It looks like only releases 3.9 and following have binaries.

Comment: Python 3.8 no longer receives bug fixes, only security fixes. This is one way to encourage you to upgrade to a version that is more fully supported.

Comment: Thank you, @chepner. That explains why there is no Windows installer. Any idea if we can still install v3.8.12 on Windows? Do we need to make a Windows installer ourselves, or bypass this version and go to v3.9.x?

Comment: I've expanded my comment to an answer which addresses that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches provides a summary of the various release statuses.

> features
> new features, bugfixes, and security fixes are accepted.
>
> prerelease
>  feature fixes, bugfixes, and security fixes are accepted
> for the upcoming feature release.
>
> bugfix 
>  bugfixes and security fixes are accepted, new binaries are
> still released. (Also called maintenance mode or stable release)
>
> security 
>  only security fixes are accepted and no more binaries are
> released, but new source-only versions can be released
>
> end-of-life
>  release cycle is frozen; no further changes can be pushed
> to it.

Python 3.8 is currently in security mode, so *only* source releases (and no binary installers) are provided from Python itself.

As the [page you linked to](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3812/) says,

> According to the release calendar specified in PEP 569, Python 3.8 is now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: 3.8 branch only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made irregularly in source-only form until October 2024. Python 3.8 isn't receiving regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer provided for it. Python 3.8.10 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.8 with binary installers.

Python 3.8.10 was the last release at the bug fix stage, and so the last for which Python officially provided binary installers. If you want a binary installers for 3.8.12, you'll have to either make one yourself from the source or find someone else who has done it or will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build it by following the [instructions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/PCbuild/readme.txt).
Add the resulting `PCbuild\win32` directory to `PATH` and you are good to go.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32324392)

Answer (score 1):

I installed one from here: https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWindows

The only plausible explanation for them not providing binaries seems to be "out of spite".

Comment: Everybody has right to dislike official decisions, but apparently there are whole slew of fanatics who declares people that voice their dislikes or find ways to satisfy their own need as blaphemous and shall be burnt alive with their families and pets together. Totally disgusting community.

Comment: Haha although I'm sure they have enough free work to do without adding/maintaining installers for minor versions outdated when you can install earlier one and upgrade the packages.